# IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сделал код:

```
await state.update_data(here_position_owner=message.text)
@dp.message_handler(IsAdmin(), content_types="photo" state="here_position_photo")
async def product_position_create_photo(message: Message  state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        position_name = clear_html(data['here_position_name'])
        position_price = data['here_position_price']
        category_id = data['here_cache_change_category_id']
        position_description = data['here_position_description']
    await state.finish()
```

Ошибка:

```
File "<string>", line 371
    @dp.message_handler(IsAdmin(),  
   content_types="photo" state="here_position_photo")
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Comment: В приведенном коде нет ошибок с отступами (разве что в первой редакции вопроса, где у await state.update_data была куча пробелов, там могли быть с этим какие-то проблемы). Имеет смысл привести более полный кусок кода.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка эта не простая, потому что там в принципе и нет проблем с индентацией.

Конкретно в этом случае вам нужно поставить запятые там, где они нужны:

```py
await state.update_data(here_position_owner=message.text)
@dp.message_handler(IsAdmin(), content_types="photo", state="here_position_photo") # №1 тут
async def product_position_create_photo(message: Message, state: FSMContext): # №2 тут.
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        position_name = clear_html(data['here_position_name'])
        position_price = data['here_position_price']
        category_id = data['here_cache_change_category_id']
        position_description = data['here_position_description']

    await state.finish()
```

Обязательно всегда следите за синтаксисом кода. Любой неправильный символ в коде может обернуться непонятной с первого раза ошибкой. И **невнимательность может обернуться опасной уязвимостью**.

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте

Comment: всё так-же и осталось

Comment: @Sl1k что осталось? Ошибка?

Comment: Пишите подробнее.

Comment: да, ошибка так и осталась

Comment: @Sl1k посмотрите новый код

Comment: посмотрел, ошибка так и осталась

Comment: Ой, извините, это совсем не то, вам нужно следить за запятыми.

Comment: Сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: @Sl1k так нет ошибки?

Comment: есть, ошибка осталась

Comment: @Sl1k всё таже ошибка? Можете показать traceback?

Comment: Или у вас [такой](https://pastebin.com/rXVz8SiP) код?

Comment: а как его посмотреть?

Comment: Нажмите "Ok, show me the paste"

Comment: @Sl1k Так всё?.